# Automated action to update the qty in hand instead of forecast qty

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

We are working on several Sales Platform (e.g. Prime Minister, Ebay) that generate an excel to import in our **Odoo 11 SAAS server**.

As there are hundred of orders, we created an automated action to update the quote to sale after importing from excel.

At that point I am able to search the action for confirming the sales in a odoo studio video.

How to update the qty on hand or change the done qty for the product and delivery?

We searched for days and still didn't get a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you confirmed the sale order by your program, forecasted qty will be decreased. Now on hand qty will be updated when you will process the delivery orders for that.

Comment: Actually we need to automate the validation for the delivery orders, but yet we are not able to do that on an automation process to the module transfer with the following function call:
record.force_assign()
record.action_done()

Comment: You need to call all methods that comes across while performing through view. Check qty, assign lot if tracked products, do procurement for less qty & then make it done. Check all possible scenario & do code for that.

Comment: is there anyway to massive confirm the delivery manually? In the delivery list we are able to massive print delivery slip, export and delete, but there is no validate or confirm option. It is quite difficult for us to do large amount of coding as we are not very familiar with python